# How to add file to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a file where all the  column delimiters at Notepad++ are shown as `EOT, SOH, ETX, ACK, BEL, BS, ENQ`

I know the schema of the table but I am totally new at these technologies and I cannot load the file to the table. Can I do it through UI like CSV file, and if yes with what delimiter?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy as you have mentioned the file is "," saparated.

lets create a simple table with 1 column.

```
CREATE TABLE test1(col1 STRING);
     Row format delimited 
     Fields terminated by ',';
```

Please note statement **Fields terminated by ','** we have given fields are saparated by "," if it columns are saparated by tab we can change it to "\t"

once the table is create we can load the file using the below commands.

If File is on local file system

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '<complete_local_file_path>' INTO table test1;
```

If File is in HDFS

```
  LOAD DATA INPATH '<complete_HDFS_file_path>' INTO table test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive is just an abstraction layer over HDFS, so you would add the file to HDFS in some folder, then build an `EXTERNAL TABLE`;over top of it

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE name(...)
STORED AS TEXT 
LINE FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LOCATION '/path/to/folder/' 
;
```

> Can I do it through UI like CSV file

If you install HUE, then you could